# go get error - can't load package

Tags: oauth, go, oauth-2.0

I am new to golang and I am trying to get a package but I get a strange error and can't seem to figure out what the problem is?

```
padlar@padlar:~/workspace-go$ echo $GOPATH
/home/padlar/workspace-go

padlar@padlar:~/workspace-go$ go get golang.org/x/oauth2
padlar@padlar:~/workspace-go$ ls ~/workspace-go/src/golang.org/x/oauth2/
    AUTHORS            google/            jwt_test.go        README.md          
    CONTRIBUTORS       internal/          LICENSE            transport.go       
    example_test.go    jws/               oauth2.go          transport_test.go  
    .git/              jwt.go             oauth2_test.go     .travis.yml        

padlar@padlar:~/workspace-go$ ls ~/workspace-go/pkg/linux_amd64/golang.org/x/oauth2
oauth2/   oauth2.a  
padlar@padlar:~/workspace-go$ ls ~/workspace-go/pkg/linux_amd64/golang.org/x/oauth2/
internal.a  jws.a
padlar@padlar:~/workspace-go$ go get github.com/golang/oauth2
can't load package: package github.com/golang/oauth2: code in directory /home/padlar/workspace-go/src/github.com/golang/oauth2 expects import "golang.org/x/oauth2"
```

Comment: There's a branch of this project called `importpath` that I think fixes this. the README states it's a work in progress, so I guess it's not complete yet. Just import it from the old path.

Comment: Have you already tried running `go get -u -a`, which will update all dependencies (forcing those up-to-date)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using `go get` on two different import paths. The new path,

```
go get golang.org/x/oauth2
```

and the old path

```
go get github.com/golang/oauth2
```

This confuses the Go tool chain. Consistently use the new import path

```
go get golang.org/x/oauth2
```