# Go Wants to Import Package From Comment

Tags: go

I'm experiencing a weird phenomenon. I have the executable package importing a library package. However, the library has a comment after the package name mentioning an import path. When Go attempts to build the library package it gives an "expects import" error. It doesn't happen when the comment is before or after the package statement.

Executable package:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/dsoprea/import_confusion_lib"
)

func main() {

}
```

Library package:

```
package mypackage // import "extraneous/import/path"
```

When I run the build:

```
GOPATH=`pwd`/import_confusion_root go build github.com/dsoprea/import_confusion
```

Output:

```
import_confusion_root/src/github.com/dsoprea/import_confusion/app.go:4:5: code in directory /home/dustin/development/go/test/import_confusion_root/src/github.com/dsoprea/import_confusion_lib expects import "extraneous/import/path"
```

Looks like a bug to me. Can anyone explain this or otherwise corroborate that it's a bug?

Comment: From the docs: [Import Path Checking](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Import_path_checking)

Comment: Thanks. Would be better if you posted that and a brief summary as an answer. Can't close the question this way.

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344013/go-get-error-cant-load-package http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330303/forcing-a-specific-import-path-in-go

Comment: Not a duplicate because I'm trying to explain the phenomenon and searches for the error will lead here. I'm not trying to solve a problem (which is the purpose of the other topics).